# Has key check for a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a an if check that uses has.key:

```
    if self.has_key(observer.key):
```

and i am trying to replace it to use the `in` keyword.

I have tried doing:

```
    if observer.key in self:
    # 
    if observer.key in self.__dict__:
```

But neither of them work returning:

```
    E       TypeError: argument of type 'Observers' is not iterable
```

Comment: What exactly is the type of `self` in this code?  Where is that `has_key` method coming from - does the class inherit it from `dict`, or does it contain its own implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class had a has_key method deep inside, which did this functionality but i assume pycharm though it was the builtin method:

```
def has_key(self, key):
    return key in self.keys
```